# How can i add custom fonts in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

To add custom fonts in cocos2d-x i followed the following steps.

1. Download a font.
2. paste it in resource file of my project without any subfolder.
3. Add my font in info.plist in Fonts provided by application as Roboto-thin.ttf
4. Add it in Copy bundle resources.

I used the following code to display the font:

```
CCLabelTTF* cycleLabel1 = CCLabelTTF::create(" ", "Roboto-Thin.ttf", 80);
```

I tried with removing the extension also in the code, but no use. Anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Check the console to see what the error is. If it isn't working then you must be able to see something. i.e. not found, etc. Plus, you are not putting in any text. i.e. CCLabelTTF* cycleLabel1 = CCLabelTTF::create(" Hello Raj", "Roboto-Thin.ttf", 80);

Answer (score 0):

On IOS, inside your CCLabelTTF::create() you have to use the NAME of the font, not the file of the font. In your case it is probably "Roboto Thin". Something like this:

```
CCLabelTTF* cycleLabel1 = CCLabelTTF::create(" ", "Roboto Thin", 80);
```

You can see font names installing them and opening them in Font Book (assuming you use mac)
Note on Android you still call fonts using its file name.

It is very explained (not very well at all) in the documentation.
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Use_Custom_TTF_Font_on_iOS

Comment: Check your fonts are inside the Resources folder. Also, if you have the fonts in a folder(e.g. "fonts"), then in the plist file u have to specify the folder "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf" but in the call you just need to use the name of the font without the folder. In case this is not your issue, make sure there isn't spelling mistakes. The process is case sensitive, so use upper and lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AddFontResource(L"xxx/yyy/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
```

before `CCLabelTTF::create(" ", "Roboto-Thin", 80);`

and then `RemoveFontResource(L"xxx/yyy/Roboto-Thin.ttf");`

Make sure that the name of the font and the file name are the same